# Вывод отделения с наибольшим количеством букв

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT
DEPARTMENT_NAME,
LENGTH(DEPARTMENT_NAME) as "product_name_length"
FROM
HR.DEPARTMENTS
ORDER BY LENGTH(DEPARTMENT_NAME) ASC, DEPARTMENT_NAME ASC LIMIT 1
```

Надо найти отделение в название которого наибольшее количество букв. Я пытался гуглить, но синтаксис видимо не oracle. Помогите исправить кто может

Answer (score 1):

Ни это?

```
SELECT MAX(LENGHT(your_col))
FROM your_table
```

Comment: там еще имя отдела надо